# custom assert in pytest should overrule standard assert

Tags: assert, pytest

I wrote a custom assert function to compare items in two lists such that the order is not important, using pytest_assertrepr_compare. This works fine and reports a failure when the content of the lists differ.

However, if the custom assert passes, it fails on the default '==' assert because item 0 of one list is unequal to item 0 of the other list.

Is there a way to prevent the default assert to kick in?

```py
assert ['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['b', 'a', 'c'] # custom assert passes 
                                          # default assert fails
```

The custom assert function is:

```py
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(config, op, left, right):
    equal = True
    if op == '==' and isinstance(left, list) and isinstance(right, list):
        if len(left) != len(right):
            equal = False
        else:
            for l in left:
                if not l in right:
                    equal = False
        if equal:
            for r in right:
                if not r in left:
                    equal = False
    if not equal:
        return ['Comparing lists:',
                '   vals: %s != %s' % (left, right)]
```

Comment: `pytest_assertrepr_compare` is for custom assertion failure messages. It doesn't do the actual comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found easiest way to combinate [py.test](http://pytest.org) & [pyhamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest). In your example it is easy to use `contains_inanyorder` matcher:

```python
from hamcrest import assert_that, contains_inanyorder
    
def test_first():
    assert_that(['a', 'b', 'c'], contains_inanyorder('b', 'a', 'c'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a python set

```py
assert set(['a', 'b', 'c']) == set(['b', 'a', 'c'])
```

This will return true

Comment: Does not work if you want to compare also the number of items.

Comment: ... if there are duplicate items. Although, I also have an issue with this, my objects aren't hashable (i.e. dicts)

Comment: To cope with dupped and just ignore the order:

`assert list(sorted(['a', 'b', 'c'])) == list(sorted(['b', 'a', 'c']))`